# How much data available in table using row count not working

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, ios4

I want to check at the load time of application whether data is available or not in the `table` so for that I using following code on the viewload of my first file if available then move to other file else retain same but it can't give perfect result mainly row `count` is not working

```
 NSString *dbPath;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPath;
    int count=0;

    dirPath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir=[dirPath objectAtIndex:0];

    dbPath=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TimerDataBaseMain.db"]];


    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: dbPath] == YES)
    {
        const char *databsPath=[dbPath UTF8String];


        NSLog(@"from created;");
        if(sqlite3_open(databsPath,&sqlDatabase) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            const char *query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRJDATA";
            sqlite3_stmt *statement;
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlDatabase, query, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
                while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    count++;
                    NSLog(@"from count");
                }
                NSLog(@"from row count");
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(sqlDatabase);
    }

        if (count>0) {
        ListEventCreated *listObject=[[ListEventCreated alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListEventCreated" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        listObject.title=@"List of event";
        NSLog(@"from if condition");
            NSLog(@"%i",count);
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:listObject animated:YES];
        [listObject release];
        listObject=nil;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe , this is **WRONG**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) PRJDATA
```

You should use this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRJDATA
```

Comment: by mistake old code is posted but with SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRJDATA not working man.

Comment: what do you mean by not working ??? count will work, it is not user define function. So, it will show output, when you used that correctly.

Comment: In my solution, i have mentioned correct sql query, if it is not working. Then, you have done something wrong in your code. Check it properly.

Comment: i change my variable count to cnt this is not my worry but if no any record in the database then also it return 1 number means it execute while loop anyhow thats fault